# How to add templates for datagrid columns?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, itemsource

I'm  adding dynamically an itemsource to the datagrid:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = _table.DefaultView;
            foreach (DataColumn column in _table.Columns)
            {
                if (column.DataType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    var dgrcl = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                        {
                            IsThreeState = false,
                            Header = column.Caption,
                            Binding = new Binding(column.ColumnName),
                            Width = new DataGridLength(15, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
                        };
                    datagrid.Columns.Add(dgrcl);
                }
                else
                {
                    var dgrcl = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    dgrcl.Binding = new Binding(column.ColumnName);
                    dgrcl.Header = column.Caption;
                    datagrid.Columns.Add(dgrcl);
                }
            }
```

But if I add a new row to Datagrid (with checkboxcolumn) - the checkbox is threestate.
I tried to add next code in xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="dgrChkBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsThreeState" Value="False"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"></Setter>
        </Style>   
<DataGrid Name="datagrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternatingRowBackground="Honeydew" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgrChkBoxStyle}"></Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid>
```

But there is exception that "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource".

I am new in WPF,please any advise, how to make checkboxes with only two states?

Answer (score 0):

you should write the column definition like so :

```
  <DataGrid Name="datagrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternatingRowBackground="Honeydew" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgrChkBoxStyle}"></Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` directly. How about?

```
<Style x:Key="DgCheckBoxColumnStyle" x:TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCheckBoxColumn}">
    <Setter Property="IsThreeState" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Binding" Value="{Binding <SomePath>, TargetNullValue="True"}" />
</Style>

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Style="{StaticResource DgCheckBoxColumnStyle}" />
```

For more information, please refer to the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Should be easier than how you're trying to achieve it.

If you really want to access the controls in the columns you must provide one style for [DataGridBoundColumn.ElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and one for [DataGridBoundColumn.EditingElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).